# object not moving with the key being pressed (javascript + canvas)

Tags: javascript, html, web, canvas, html5-canvas

in this code I've been trying to move a rectangle using the arrow keys on my keyboard. I've written the conditions based on [this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Tutorials/2D_Breakout_game_pure_JavaScript/Paddle_and_keyboard_controls) but my project is slightly different so I changed the code but the object the problem still exist.

I have 2 event listeners for keys being pressed and not pressed and I used some flag variables to see the state of buttons and move the object based on it.

Sorry if my question is silly, I'm newbie with this area of programming and I've spent couple of hours on it but I couldn't solve the problem.

```
    <script>
            //canvas
            var canvas = document.getElementById("gameScreen");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");          
            const width = 1000;
            const height = 700;
            
            //user controllers
            var rightPressed = false;
            var leftPressed = false;
            var upPressed = false;
            var downPressed = false;

            //keydown handler
            document.addEventListener("keydown",(e)=>{
                if(e.key == "Up" || e.key == "ArrowUp"){
                    upPressed = true;
                } 
                else if(e.key == "Down" || e.key == "ArrowDown"){
                    downPressed = true;
                }
                else if(e.key == "Right" || e.key == "ArrowRIght"){
                    rightPressed = true;
                }
                else if(e.key == "Left" || e.key == "ArrowLeft"){
                    leftPressed = true;
                }
            }, false);

            //keyup handler
            document.addEventListener("keyup",(e)=>{
                if(e.key == "Up" || e.key == "ArrowUp"){
                    upPressed = false;
                } 
                else if(e.key == "Down" || e.key == "ArrowDown"){
                    downPressed = false;
                }
                else if(e.key == "Right" || e.key == "ArrowRIght"){
                    rightPressed = false;
                }
                else if(e.key == "Left" || e.key == "ArrowLeft"){
                    leftPressed = false;
                }
            }, false);          
            
            // Player Object
            let Player = function(x,y){
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y; 
                this.width = 50;
                this.height = 50;

                this.getDirection = function(){
                    if(downPressed){
                        this.y -= 10;
                    }else if(upPressed){
                        this.y += 10;
                    }else if(rightPressed){
                        this.x += 10;
                    }else if(leftPressed){
                        this.x -= 10;
                    }
                }
                
                this.update = function(){
                    this.getDirection();
                    this.draw();
                                                        
                };

                this.draw = function(){
                    ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
                    ctx.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.width,this.height);
                    ctx.fill();
                };
            }

            let player = new Player(200,200)            
            let callback = player.update();

            requestAnimationFrame(callback)

            
            
        </script>
```

Comment: Maybe your problem is that you're passing the return value of `player.update` as a callback because you are calling the function, it should be `let callback = player.update;`. Also, you might need to put `requestAnimationFrame(callback);` in a `setInterval()` to get it to run continuously.

Comment: @ArkinSolomon I've just checked it but it doesn't work that way either.

Comment: The code isn't complete. Where is `callback`? I'd also add the canvas HTML and make it a runnable snippet that clearly reproduces the problem and makes it easier to help.

Comment: @ggorlen callback is just a line above requestAnimationFrame function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there were just too many errors, here is a fixed version:

```css
canvas {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="gameScreen"></canvas>

<script>
            //canvas
            var canvas = document.getElementById("gameScreen");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");          
            const width = 1000;
            const height = 700;
            
            //user controllers
            var rightPressed = false;
            var leftPressed = false;
            var upPressed = false;
            var downPressed = false;

            //keydown handler
            document.addEventListener("keydown",(e)=>{
                if(e.key == "Up" || e.key == "ArrowUp"){
                    upPressed = true;
                } 
                else if(e.key == "Down" || e.key == "ArrowDown"){
                    downPressed = true;
                }
                else if(e.key == "Right" || e.key == "ArrowRight"){
                    rightPressed = true;
                }
                else if(e.key == "Left" || e.key == "ArrowLeft"){
                    leftPressed = true;
                }
            }, false);

            //keyup handler
            document.addEventListener("keyup",(e)=>{
                if(e.key == "Up" || e.key == "ArrowUp"){
                    upPressed = false;
                } 
                else if(e.key == "Down" || e.key == "ArrowDown"){
                    downPressed = false;
                }
                else if(e.key == "Right" || e.key == "ArrowRight"){
                    rightPressed = false;
                }
                else if(e.key == "Left" || e.key == "ArrowLeft"){
                    leftPressed = false;
                }
            }, false);          
            
            // Player Object
            let Player = function(x,y){
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y; 
                this.width = 50;
                this.height = 50;

                this.getDirection = () => {
                    if(downPressed){
                        this.y += 10;
                    }else if(upPressed){
                        this.y -= 10;
                    }else if(rightPressed){
                        this.x += 10;
                    }else if(leftPressed){
                        this.x -= 10;
                    }
                }
                
                this.update = () => {
                    this.getDirection();
                    this.draw();
                                                        
                };

                this.draw = () => {
                    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
                    ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
                    ctx.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.width,this.height);
                    ctx.fill();
                    requestAnimationFrame(this.update)
                };
            }

            let player = new Player(10,10);          
            let callback = player.update;

            requestAnimationFrame(callback)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, after couple of hours of struggling with a silly problem and digging into websites I finally got the error and I've fixed it.

The error is occurred where I was using `requestAnimationFrame` and it was all about my lack of knowledge on the functionality of `requestAnimationFrame`.

if you want to use a function inside `requestAnimationFrame`, you should use an empty function and use the main function inside it so that it would be a callback.